# A simple calculus of variations problem

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I'm trying to solve the following problem: Suppose  $F:\mathbb{R_+}\to\mathbb{R_+}$ is a given decreasing function with $F(0)=1$ and $F(\infty)=0$. 
\begin{align*}
&\min{\int_0^{\infty} F(t) e^{-M(t)}}\textrm{d}t\\
{\textrm{st.}} & \int_0^{\infty} F(t) e^{-M(t)} M'(t) \textrm{d}t \leq \alpha,
\end{align*}
with  $\alpha\in(0,1)$.  The problem is finding  $M:\mathbb{R_+}\to\mathbb{R_+}$ with the boundary condition $M(0)=0$ such that the objective is minimized and  the constraint  is satisfied. Any input would  be appreciated!

Update: When $F(t)=e^{-t}$, I conjecture that the solution  is the linear function $M(t)=\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}t$, but  cannot prove this.

Comment: I  am also interested to the  special case where $F(t)=e^{-\beta t}$ for $\beta>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the problem without the inequality constraint. If you find a minimal solution that satisfies the constraint, you’re done. If not, the minimum must lie on the boundary, so you can replace the inequality by an equality and solve the constrained problem using a Lagrange multiplier.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have tried this method but haven't been able to get it right. Also, the method gives local optimality (i.e., stability through Euler-Lagrange equation) but  I think not necessarily shows that the result is global minimum..?

Comment: @afshi7n: OK, I'll work it out, then, and expand the answer. Please note that this is one of the reasons why a good question contains information about what you've already tried yourself – see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that would be great. (and I looked at your link, will include more next  time..)

Comment: To be more specific, when I simplify the Euler-Lagrange equation, I get to $\lambda=-F'(t)/F(t)$ with no $M$ involved (the $M$ cancels out). Happy to add this my derivation to the description if it helps..